# Who is the T-Boner, and who is the T-Bonee?

Tags: slang

Imagine this scenario: A motorcycle is riding along the top of a T-intersection. A car pulls out at the intersection into the path of the motorcycle, and the motorcycle hits the car.

This type of accident is commonly referred to by the slang term "T-bone".

Now, the question is, did the car T-bone the motorcycle, or did the motorcycle T-bone the car?

Comment: We normally say the one that got hit (in your example, the car) was *T-boned*.

Comment: The construction is that the vertical shaft of the "T" comes straight up to hit the middle of the horizontal line. If it was the other way around, the vehicle representing the horizontal line in the letter "T" would need to be travelling sideways. That's possible, but it's not the normal case.

Comment: @Lawrence, if I understand you correctly, the bike hits the car so it is the do-er, the subject, of the verb. That makes sense. But on the other hand, it is the car that is the agent that causes the accident, so maybe it should be the subject of the verb.

Comment: I don’t think that matters. See my comment above about the construction of the term, and also consider: *he drove out and got himself T-boned by the motorcyclist*. But if who was at fault matters, you might have to use a term other than *T-bone* in this context.

Comment: Then again, perhaps you’re right in implying that *T-bone* isn’t just a description of fact but carries a connotation of guilt as well (note the words *got himself* in my example above). As a matter related to striking, it’s unusual that the one struck is the guilty party.

Comment: @Lawrence surely that depends: "he pulled cautiously out of the side road and was T-boned by the car speeding out of the blind bend" makes it pretty clear that the fault lies with the T-boner in this case

Comment: @ChrisH No controversy there. In the OP's case, the one who got T-boned was (presumably) at fault.

Comment: @Lawrence I think there's an interesting gap between the agent of the action in linguistic terms, and the agent in terms the insurance companies would be worried about, which you hinted at. I wanted to provide a stronger example and give those who use the term regularly somethign to argue with (it's not common here in the UK)

Answer (score 1):

Since T-boner and T-bonee are not in the dictionary, let's compare to similar words which are:

> [Employer](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/employer), from MW:
>
> one that employs or makes use of something or somebody

So, the **employer** is the subject, or the (more) active participant; the **doer**, or the *one who does something*.

> [Employe](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/employee), also from MW:
>
> one employed by another...

So, the **employee** is the object, or the (more) passive participant; the **doee**, or the *one to whom something is done*.

The normal interpretation would be that the T-boner is the one *(in your example, the motorcycle (and, by extension, the motorcyclist))* who drives into the T-bonee *(in your example, the car (and, by extension, the driver of the car)).*

Either may have been at fault, but the motorcycle impacted (T-boned) the car.

Edit to add image:

[image: Vehicle T-bones Harris County sergeant patrol car, officials say]

Comment: It is the car driver who is doing the thing, I would say. It is their act of will that causes the accident. The motorcyclist has no choice in the matter. Something is being done to the motorcyclist.

Comment: Not necessarily. The motorcycle may have run a stop sign. Something has happened to each party, but there is not enough information to place cause.

Comment: There is enough information. It was my example. I get to set the terms of my own example. The car in my example was 100% at fault.

Answer (score 1):

It seems clear that the motorcyclist is the T-Boner. However, saying so carries a pretty strong implication that the motorcyclist was at fault, which doesn't sound like the case. In other words, it seems misleading to say the motorcyclist T-boned the car without providing clarifying context.

Comment: This in no way implies fault. A hit B, regardless of who was at fault. A T-boned B. Did A fail to yield? Did B? We don't know.

Comment: Well, I'm certain your opinion that there's absolutely no connotation of fault is probably superior to my opinion that there often is a connotation of fault. But I hope you will understand if I don't change my opinion, anyway.

Comment: The original post did not indicate any traffic control measures that had been followed or neglected. In this case, I would expect the car to have had a stop sign, and the motorcycle to have none, but that is not a fact in evidence at the time this was posted. However, I see that as irrelevant regarding which vehicle T-boned which. I look forward to seeing evidence to the contrary, that I might improve in my knowledge of this fascinating and seemingly under-documented term.

Comment: From a purely logical perspective you are completely correct. The question is only whether the verb carries any connotation of guilt on the part of the subject if it's not completely clear in context. I maintain that if I say "the car T-boned me," most listeners would assume I was probably blaming the other car's driver unless I specifically added "but it wasn't his fault." If a lot of people are likely to make the same assumption, then there is probably a connotation. I have no empirical data, though, and could certainly be wrong.